# QTest: It's possible to test drag&drop?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qtestlib

I try to test drag&drop with simple sequince: mousePress + mouseMove + mouseRelease. But it's not work.

I investigate qtest source and found, that move event tested through main dispatcher processEvent(). Also I found some bugs in qt bug-tracker: [1](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13397), [2](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-5232)

So, I think, that it's not possible to test drag&drop under latest stable Qt4. Have anybody success story with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had no luck simulating drag and drop via the QTest mouse functions, and [digia says](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13397)
they're not adding that functionality to QT4. I implemented drag/drop testing via a method similar to the one suggested in the above link:

create your mime_data, something like:

```
mime_data = widget_model.mimeData(indexes)
```

or

```
mime_data = QMimeData()
mime_data.setText(widget.text())
```

then use a function like this to drop the data:

```
def dropOnto(self, widget, mime_data):
    action = Qt.CopyAction|Qt.MoveAction
    pt = widget.rect().center()
    drag_drop = QDropEvent(pt, action, mime_data, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
    drag_drop.acceptProposedAction()
    widget.dropEvent(drag_drop)
```

Answer (score 0):

`mouseMoveEvent()` handler starts and blocks at `QDrag.exec()`. In order to simulate the drop, you have to schedule it e.g. with `QTimer`:

```py
def complete_qdrag_exec():
    QTest.mouseMove(drop_target)
    QTest.qWait(50)
    QTest.mouseClick(drop_target, Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)

QTimer.singleShot(1000, complete_qdrag_exec)
QTest.mousePress(drag_source, Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton, Qt.KeyboardModifier.NoModifier, QPoint(10, 10))
QTest.mouseMove(drag_source, QPoint(50, 50))  # Ensure distance sufficient for DND start threshol
```